# field id expected a number but got 'ashu'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I keep getting the following error while trying to print the level:

```
field id expected a number but got 'ashu'
```

And here's my code:

```
class User(models.Model):

    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sport(models.Model):

    sport=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Intrest(models.Model):

    sport_name=models.ForeignKey(Sport,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    LEVEL=(('1','Beginner'),
    ('2','Mediate'),
    ('3','Advance'),
    )
    level=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=LEVEL)


# code sample
A=Intrest.objects.get(user=uder.Host.user_name)
print(a.level)
```

Comment: What is `uder` here?

Comment: please provide full view which contains this line `A=Intrest.objects.get(user=uder.Host.user_name)`.